# Noun for "lack of exercise"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Once upon a time, I saw a short, proper and single word for "lack of exercise", but I forgot it.

Comment: As a side note, there must be no whitespace before a comma or a period in English (or in *any* language, for that matter). I have edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

A lifestyle devoid of physical activity is usually described as *sedentary*, as for example in this Wikipedia article on [Sedentary Lifestyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedentary_lifestyle).

Comment: Although this word gained the most positive votes, It's not the intended word. I's a noun not an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

I think [inactivity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inactivity) may suggest the idea:

> - the state of being inactive ,  idle or inert.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

UNHEALTHY DIETS & PHYSICAL [INACTIVITY](http://www.who.int/nmh/publications/fact_sheet_diet_en.pdf)

> - Unhealthy diets (especially those which have a high content in fats, free sugars and salt) and physical inactivity are among some of the leading causes of noncommunicable diseases (NCDs) including cardiovascular diseases (CVD).

Source: www.who.int/nmh/publications (World Health Organization)

Comment: It's similar to this one, but it is not the intended word. @Josh61

Comment: If you konw any similiar word, please post it. whether it's a slang or a formal term. @Josh61

Comment: @mohamed: SLOTH :Aversion to work or exertion; laziness; indolence.  RUST : Deterioration, as of ability, resulting from inactivity or neglect.

Answer (score 0):

According to ODO:

> [sed·en·tar·y](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sedentary)
>   ˈsednˌterē/Submit
>   adjective
>   (of a person) tending to spend much time seated; somewhat inactive.
>   synonyms:   sitting, seated, desk-bound, stationary; More
>   (of work or a way of life) characterized by much sitting and little physical exercise.
>   synonyms:   sitting, seated, desk-bound, stationary; More
>   (of a position) sitting; seated.
>   synonyms:   sitting, seated, desk-bound, stationary; More

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this community seeks to provide a library of *definitive* answers, and as such has a higher standard than the average Internet forum. Copying and pasting a dictionary definition, without bothering to remove extraneous link text, but most importantly *without providing a citation* will earn a poor reception; I have done that minimum for you. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***flab***?

> The condition of being flabby: *Most of the new recruits had run to flab in civilian life*.
>
> flabby: having flabby flesh, esp. through being overweight
> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flab?s=t)

Alternately, consider:

***out-of-shapeness***

> The condition of being out of shape
>
> **out of shape** *and* **out of condition**: not in good physical condition. *I get out of breath when I run because I'm out of shape. Keep exercising regularly, or you'll get out of condition*. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+shape)

***overweight***

> Weight in excess of what is considered normal, proper, or healthful [Random House](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+shape)

***obesity***

> The condition of being obese; increased body weight caused by excessive accumulation of fat. [FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/obese)